# Asp .Net UpdatePanel not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am using an `UpdatePanel` to show some controls that are normally hidden.

This is the code that I am using:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" class="btn blue h27" CausesValidation="false" ID="lnkSuggestArticle"
                OnClick="lnkSuggestArticle_Click"><%=Supplier.GetResource("Answers_lnkSuggestArticle")%> <i class="icon icon_next_02 fr"></i></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="infoRequest" id="divSuggestion" runat="server" visible="false">
                        <br class="clearfix" />
                        <h3>
                            Please provide the information you want to see on our support site:</h3>
                        <br class="clearfix" />
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSuggestArticle" Rows="10" ValidationGroup="s" Width="100%"
                            TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        <div id="divEmailAddress" runat="server" visible="false">
                            <br />
                            <h3>
                                Please enter your email address</h3>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmailAddress" Rows="1" ValidationGroup="s" CssClass="suggestionEmail"
                                TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSugestedArticleError" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSaveSuggestion" ValidationGroup="s" runat="server" OnClick="btnSaveSuggestion_Click"
                            CssClass="btn blue fr"><%=Supplier.GetResource("createticket_btnSuggest")%> <i class="icon icon_next_02 fr"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                        <%--<input type="submit" value="Suggest" class="btnSuggest" />--%>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <p id="notice" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSuggestionNote" /></p>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkSuggestArticle" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When the user clicks the `lnkSuggestArticle` button I execute the following code:

```
protected void lnkSuggestArticle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    divSuggestion.Visible = true;
    if ((WFSS.DataAccess.Entities.Customer)Session["__currentCustomer"] == null)
    {
        divEmailAddress.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't update the page. The `div` still stays hidden when the user clicks the suggest button.

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors?

Comment: Which div of them? divEmailAddress?

Comment: Have you checked with Firebug to make sure there's no errors happening that you're not seeing? If you debug is it hitting that lnkSuggestArticle_Click method? Have you tried setting the update to conditional or explicitly adding a trigger to the update panel to see if that works?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did check and I got some errors.

Comment: you button SuggestArticle is outside the updatepanel. so move it in the update panel or make it a trigger for the updatepanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   protected void lnkSuggestArticle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    divSuggestion.Visible = true;
    if (Session["__currentCustomer"] == null)
    {
        divEmailAddress.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there was a bug in Visual Studio. I had commented a piece of code in the aspx file. Turns out even though it appeared to be commented the code still executed which caused another update panel to be added which gave me an error in javascript.